# How to convert values from select multiple into an email?

Tags: symphony-cms

How can I convert the selected `options` from a `select` multiple field into an email?

```
<select name="fields[issues][]" multiple="multiple">
     <xsl:for-each select="//issues-all/entry">
         <option value="{@id}">
           <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
         </option>
     </xsl:for-each>
</select>
```

My standard approach doesn't work unfortunately:

```
<input name="send-email[body]" value="fields[name,address,phone,issues]" type="hidden" />
```

The email gets delivered but contains the `value` as a string rather than the actual values.

What am I missing here?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this isn't a bug and the standard Symphony email event isn't supposed to be able to select options, it sounds like a job for [Email Template Manager](http://symphonyextensions.com/extensions/email_template_manager/).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to also use:

```
<input name="send-email[body]" value="fields[name],fields[address],fields[phone],fields[issues]" type="hidden" />
```

As David mentioned though, Email Template Manager or Email Template Filter are great extensions to help you build more custom emails.